# Show selective dates in kendo datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am using Kendo datepicker in the below code, and can't figure out the error.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="BlueSiteTextBold" style="text-align: left">
        @AlertResources.GetResourceStringValue("L000121", EnmResourceType.Labels)
    </td>
    <td>
        @(Html
        .Kendo()
        .DatePicker()
        .Name("DTPDatasetDate")
        //.Min(DateTime.Now)
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:240px" })
        .Events(e => e.Open("PopulateDatasetDate"))
        )
    </td>
</tr> `
</table>
```

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? I'm having a hard time understanding.

Comment: Need to show only those highlighted dates in kendo datepicker in javascript that's it

Comment: You need to edit your question and organize your code. Put 4 spaces before code lines.

Comment: Allow user to select only selective dates in kendo datepicker. For example if i have 5/5/2017 user should be able to select only this date. Rest should be grayed out.is there anyway

Answer (score 0):

Configuring  disableDates should work. Take a look at the [kendo api for implementation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#configuration-disableDates).

```
<input id="datepicker" />
<script>
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
    value: new Date(),
    disableDates: function (date) {
        var disabled = [13,14,20,21];
        if (date && disabled.indexOf(date.getDate()) > -1 ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```